# How can I fetch every row where column is not in (array of values) with Doctrine?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

I'm trying to accomplish something similar to the following SQL, but using the Doctrine API.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name NOT IN (1, 2, 3);
```

I was thinking of something like this:

```
$entityManager->getRepository($entity)->findBy(array('ID' => array('NOT IN' => array(1, 2, 3))));
```

... How far am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a DQL:

```
$result = $entityManager->createQuery("SELECT e FROM $entity e 
        WHERE e.ID NOT IN (:ids)")
    ->setParameter('ids', array(1, 2, 3), \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY)
    ->getResult();
```

Passing arrays as parameters is supported since Doctrine version 2.1.